# Input methods other than using Scanner class?

Tags: java

The only way I know to get a user input is by using the Scanner Class in my code, which (I believe) only contains these methods:

- Read a byte - `nextByte()`
- Read a short - `nextShort()`
- Read an int - `nextInt()`
- Read a long - `nextLong()`
- Read a float - `nextFloat()`
- Read a double - `nextDouble()`
- Read a boolean - `nextBoolean()`
- Read a complete line - `nextLine()`
- Read a word - `next()`

What if I want an input that doesn't requires the keyboard and proceeds only if the user clicks on the screen (for instance), how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Are you using Swing? Are you taking about standalone an application?

Comment: Are you talking about `CheckBoxes`,`radioButtons`,`MouseFocusEvent`???

Comment: what do you mean the user clicks on the screen? like a keyborad on a screen? can you provide more info?

Comment: I mean for instance, if you use a scanner class and expect a String Object from the user then the compiler waits until the String Object is entered and then proceeds accordingly but what if I want the compiler to proceed only when the user clicks anywhere on the screen.

Comment: To get mouse or touch input, you then need to have a graphical user interface (GUI), implemented using one of several GUI frameworks available. One of it is JavaFX. Search for 'javafx tutorial' to get more info.

Comment: @isnot2bad Not completely true. Check out my answer

Comment: @VinceEmigh Nice! Didn't know it.

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` is usually used to easily grab user input from the console. This is not used for mouse/key inputs.

If using Swing, you could add a `KeyListener` and `MouseListener` to your panel, which will trigger event methods containing code that you write.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

         switch(keyCode) {
             case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                 // the up arrow key was pressed
                 break;
         }
    }

    //implement other methods
});
```

I highly suggest you look into listeners: [Introduction to Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html)

If you aren't using GUI, look into [JNativeHook](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/), which comes with a NativeKeyListener and NativeMouseListener. They listen for input at any time, since they are added to your screen instead of a component.

```
GlobalScreen.getInstance().addKeyListener(new NativeKeyListener() {
    public void keyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    }

    //implement other methods
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the method to input using keyboard is to implement `KeyListener`, which offers the following methods:

- `keyTyped(KeyEvent e)`, which does a particular action when the key is typed.
- `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`, which does a particluar action when the key is pressed.
- `keyReleased(KeyEvent e)`, which does a particular action when the key is released.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in Java 8 by **using lambda expression**.

Code:

```
public class ListenerTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

  JButton testButton = new JButton("Test Button");

 testButton.addActionListener(e -> { 
   System.out.println("Click Detected by Lambda Listner");
 });

 // Swing stuff
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Listener Test");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.add(testButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);

}
  }
```

Source:

http://blueskyworkshop.com/topics/Java-Pages/lambda-expression-basics/

Tutorial

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Comment: But that's exactly the other way round, isn't it? The question was about handling mouse events, not about faking/producing them.

Comment: I just through this as an example I found and op can read more cuz it covers mouse handling as I mentioned. why u said faking?

Comment: So then please show how you can listen for a mouse click event then? Concerning 'fake': Maybe the wrong word - 'simulate' is better (e.g. `robot.mousePress(...)` simulates a mouse press event).

Comment: Unfortunately not. Your second example again just simulates events, but does not react to events from the user. I think you misunderstood the question. Simple example: Print 'Hello World' whenever the user clicks the right mouse button.

Comment: oh K thank you so much for that. I am clear right now. So Can I ask you a question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57947/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-isnot2bad).